Difficulty yielding accurate relationship in experimental values of Euler buckling load
Recently I have been having issues with the Tecquipment STR12 Euler bucking test in the accuracy of the results it has been yielding.
When minimal force is applied, the struts start bending, and the bending just progresses relative to the amount of force applied. There is no defined point when buckling occurs like it should if the force was centroidal.
After doing some reading, I assume that the load being applied is eccentric or the struts have been used and re-straightened too many times causing an uneven profile along their length meaning that the force can't effectively be applied in a way that causes force to be applied without premature bending?
At this point the best thing I could record was the point at which the force plateaus/ is at a maximum while the strut is buckling. Unfortunately with the average of 10 trials of each length of strut, the relationship that I got was  Force=1/[strut length ^(1/20)] not Force=1/[strut length ^2]
Does anyone else have similar experiences with buckling experiments? Is there a way to ensure that the load is applied in the centroid of the cross section? Is there an effective way to determine that the two faces that the struts bolt to are coplanar? Does anyone find that accuracy goes down the more that struts are used and re-straightened?  I am using 2.0 mm thick aluminum struts. Is this too thin to allow for accuracy?
Here is a video of what my tests are looking like:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KcwsGhVeQyL2hxWTRK5EoBG6zq9l2v9j/view?usp=sharing

Did you compare the results with solution of perfect beam buckling or imperfect one?

In the video the bar is already bent at the start. I suggest you measure the profile of the plate and model it in non linear FEA and compare that with your test result. FWIW my final year project partly involved building a large truss and buckling it, the calculations were spot on.
